# Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'top' in typescript

Tags: variables, typescript

This appears only if a variable is declared with name top. Works fine for any other variable.

```
let top: number = 50;
```

Here's the [playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=let%20top%3A%20number%20%3D%20-1%3B%0D%0A)

Answer (score 1):

It's because `top` is already defined. Typescript imports `window` object and it's properties. So you can not `re-declare` any of the property at global level which comes with window object like name, length etc. You can always declare such properties inside any `class` or `function`.

```
console.log(top); //logs window object
```

Run this [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=console.log(top%2C%20name%2C%20length%2C%20onplay)%3B) and see what it logs. Hope this helps.